# Coredata/swift : hasChanges not as expected

Tags: swift, core-data

This function is not acting as expected. I'm trying to nil a set of fields.The earlier section gets the correct field names, and is used in other functions. I've got about ten tables, and they all share the same context, in case that matters.

The first unexpected thing is that "yes, changes" never runs, so I presume that the `settings` object is detached from its context. Or perhaps CoreData treats nil as some kind of exception to triggering the .`hasChanges` flag?

When it runs, the save throws no errors, and the object displays as expected, displayed with the values set to nil. But there are no changes in the db.

I can save data into these fields without problem, and confirm that in the db; this problem only happens with setting the value to nil.

```
static func clearSettings(_ s : Set<PaletteElementType>? = nil) {
    guard var setting = activeSetting() else {return}
    print(setting.id)
    let cats = s ?? PaletteView.compCatButtons
    let tgts = setting.getAssociatedFieldNames(tgts: cats, clearing : true, values: false)
    for (key, val) in tgts {
        var src = Set((val as? Dictionary<FieldNameSuffixes, String>)!.values)
        if key == .catBgndButton {
            src = src.union(["opacity", "opacityStart", "opacityStartDelta","opacityEnd", "opacityEndDelta", "opacityTimer"])
        }
        for s in src {
            print(s)
            setting.setNilValueForKey(s)
            if Blocks.context!.hasChanges {
                print("yes, changes")
            }
            do {
                try Blocks.context!.save()
                print("deleted \(setting.value(forKey: s))")
            } catch { print("deadly dogs")}
        }
        print("val is \(setting)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, working when I do it this way:

```
static func clearSettings(_ s : Set<PaletteElementType>? = nil) {
    guard var setting = activeSetting() else {return}
    print(setting.id)
    let cats = s ?? PaletteView.compCatButtons
    let tgts = setting.getAssociatedFieldNames(tgts: cats, clearing : true, values: false)
    for (key, val) in tgts {
        var src = Set((val as? Dictionary<FieldNameSuffixes, String>)!.values)
        if key == .catBgndButton {
            src = src.union(["opacity", "opacityStart", "opacityStartDelta","opacityEnd", "opacityEndDelta", "opacityTimer"])
        }
        for n in setting.entity.attributesByName.enumerated() {
            if src.contains( n.element.key as String) {
                print("found one")
                setting.setNilValueForKey(n.element.key)
            }
        }
        do {
            try Blocks.context!.save()
        } catch {print("bumpy beasts")}
        print("val is \(setting)")
    }
}
```

Happy it's working, but I don't really understand the distinction here. What is the better way to handle this? I'm not chasing some super performant code, so I don't mind a few extra loops... but what's the deal?